# Sidekiq Gem with Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sidekiq

Ruby version: 1.9.3

Rails Version: 3.2.22

I have been using **delayed_job_active_record** gem since 2014 and now the application has to run lots of background jobs so decided to use sidekiq. I was trying to install **sidekiq 4.0.0** and **'redis', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.6'**, when i am doing the bundle i am getting this error:

[image]

I also have tried some other version but still i am getting this error, also i would like to know which is the compatible version of sidekiq which i can use it with ruby 1.9.3?

Also i would like to know is there any other gem versions do we need to consider like redis....?

Comment: While it doesnt answer your question, ,most of the older projects I work on use Resque for background tasks without issue

Comment: https://github.com/resque/resque

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/6b05090a1d9ede065f314b4a90c6148ec7eb9fca#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8), at sidekiq `v3.0.2`, indicates that support for Ruby 1.9 was officially dropped. So I would harzard a guess that you'd be best sticking with `v2.x`. However, you *may* find it still works for some later versions -- such as after [this commit](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/2f9258e4fe77991c526f7a65c92bcf792eef8338) which apparently "fixed" it in `v4.2.7`.

Comment: This goes without saying, though -- you're using a **very** old, insecure, unsupported version of ruby. Support was dropped for it, years ago. I would personally prioritise upgrading the software versions before refactoring the code's dependencies if at all possible; you're going to waste countless hours digging through old READMEs just to figure out what's even compatible.